# jQuery UI : Increase the padding on resizeable()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to know that is it possible to increase and decrease padding on resize instead of increase and decreasing the height.

```
$( function() {
    $( "#resizable" ).resizable({
        handles: 'n,s'
    });
 });
```

[Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/MyTests/h2cjsc5h/3/)

Update :

I actually want to know that if I resize the div I want to dynamically increase the padding on resize instead of height
[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MyTests/h2cjsc5h/6/)

*Try to resize the div from north and south position*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added a fiddle with some calculated changes.

```
$( function() {
  $( "#resizable" ).resizable({
    resize: function( event, ui ) {
      var originalHeight = ui.originalSize.height;
      var newHeight = ui.size.height;
      var pad = 5;
      if (originalHeight < newHeight) {
        pad = newHeight - originalHeight;
      }
      $(this).css('padding', pad);
    }
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aavrug/6rh7emog/1/

Comment: one thing how can I stop increasing the height because I want padding to be increase not height.

Comment: there was a problem after resizing the element when I again try to resize it. It become small

Comment: You just have to do few adjustments as per your requirement, I just coded for how to increase the padding and the the height and width.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible to include padding. Find the updated fiddle link.

```
div#resizable {
  height: 200px;
  width : 400px;
  background-color : aqua;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h2cjsc5h/4/

Comment: sorry I think you don`t understand what i mean I actually want to know that if I resize the div I want to dynamically increase the padding on resize instead of height